# Need help setting up a parsoid server on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: node.js, npm, mediawiki, parsoid

I am currently trying to setup a parsoid server for  our mediawiki site so I can install the Visual Editor extension. Currently I am trying to follow the instructions over at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/Developer_Setup#Windows_setup and have run into some issues. I got the parsoid repository cloned. After running `npm install` I ran `npm test` and I get a LOT of errors. It says to include the npm-debug.log in any support request however no such log file exists in my parsoid directory so unfortunately I can't share that information here.

I also thought to try configuring parsoid by following instructions here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/Setup#Configuration but I can't find anything called `settings.js` or `localsettings.js`

It should be noted I'm very new to using mediawiki and have no experience with parsoid. So after all that rambling I guess my question is, has anyone else got parsoid working on a windows server? Should I try to go the other route of using Vagrant? I'd really like to get visual editor running on our wiki but so far its been nothing but a complicated mess for me.

Comment: Ahh sorry mate, I got this working the other month but have totally forgotten. I'm about to run through it again so I'll let you know

Comment: Have you considered switching to Linux? May be easier.